# Piezo with Python

Tags: python

I've found Piezo example for Rpi with specific libraries in Java and C (wiring) -- are there any for Python?
I've seen PyPiezo but it seems to be for specific hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone who knows a lot more than I may post a super example that blows this out of the water -- but basically, one can use PWM to control a Piezo on Pi, e.g.:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import time 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT) 

c = 261
d = 294
e = 329
f = 349
g = 392
a = 440
b = 493
C = 423
r = 1
p = GPIO.PWM(15, 100)
def Blink(numTimes, speed):
    for i in range(0,numTimes): 
        print "Iteration " + str(i+1) 
        GPIO.output(7, True) 
        GPIO.output(15, True) 
        time.sleep(speed) ## Wait
        p.start(100)             # start the PWM on 100  percent duty cycle  
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(90)   # change the duty cycle to 90%  
        p.ChangeFrequency(c)  # change the frequency to 261 Hz (floats also work)  
        time.sleep(speed) ## Wait
        p.ChangeFrequency(d)  # change the frequency to 294 Hz (floats also work)  
        time.sleep(speed) ## Wait
        p.ChangeFrequency(e)   
        time.sleep(speed) ## Wait
        p.ChangeFrequency(f)  
        time.sleep(speed) ## Wait
        p.ChangeFrequency(g)    
        time.sleep(speed) ## Wait
        p.ChangeFrequency(a)    
        time.sleep(speed) ## Wait
        p.ChangeFrequency(b)    
        time.sleep(speed) ## Wait
        p.ChangeFrequency(C)    
        time.sleep(speed) ## Wait
        p.ChangeFrequency(r)  
        time.sleep(speed) ## Wait
        p.stop()                # stop the PWM output  

    print "Done" ## When loop is complete, print "Done"
    GPIO.cleanup()

iterations = 4
speed = 2

Blink(int(iterations),float(speed))
```

This answer is just a conglomeration of an [Arduino example](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PlayMelody) and [basic LED stuff](http://www.thirdeyevis.com/pi-page-2.php).